# Different results in Chrome's F12 and CDP

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp, chrome-remote-debugging

The page https://www.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/live/bbcone

I can query element “div.p_playerControls”  in Chrome's F12 console:

```
document.querySelector('div.p_playerControls')
    ==> div class=​"p_playerControls" style=​"display:​ block;​ clip:​ rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px)​;​"
```

...but cannot via remote interface:

```
result1 = await Runtime.evaluate({expression:"document.querySelector('div.p_playerControls')"})
result2 = await Runtime.evaluate({expression:"document.querySelector('.player__container')"})
console.log(result1.result.className)
console.log(result2.result.className)
```

Output:

```
Debugger attached.
undefined
HTMLDivElement
```

Am I do something wrong?.. :) Thanks!

[please see this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TsrA.jpg)

Comment: It means the element is added by the page script later. Use Page.waitForSelector instead of Runtime.evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved (elements from different frames). Details here https://github.com/hardkoded/puppeteer-sharp/issues/1465